# What is pinched off current?

Tags: transistors, jfet

I know what pinch off voltage is.It is the gate-source voltage at which drain current is cut off completely (pinched off) is called the pinch-off voltage.

But what is pinched off current?

Comment: That small current that flows during pinch-off

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: As why it flows and how.

Comment: Your statement that "drain current is cut off completely" at pinch-off is not correct.

Comment: My prof told me so

Comment: @Elliot Alderson

Comment: Read some where both the view points are correct in stack exchange only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For any particular gate-source bias voltage, when the drain-source voltage reaches a certain value, the characteristic of drain-source voltage vs drain current becomes a near-straight horizontal line. This is the "pinched-off" current and it is near constant with changes to drain-source voltage.

Picture taken from [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-pinch-off-effect-of-MOSFET) quora page for convenience.

Here's another picture showing the characteristic with different gate bias voltages but this time it's for a JFET (hence negative gate voltages with respect to source): -

[image]